# Android Animated Vector Drawable: change rotation degree at runtime

Tags: android, animation, vector, rotation

I'm trying to make an Android vector animation, which contains a rotation on a vectorial group. Basically, if the degree transition would be constant, I would use those resources:

My VectorDrawable:

```
<vector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:width="64dp" 
    android:height="64dp" 
    android:viewportHeight="600" 
    android:viewportWidth="600">
    <group
        android:name="myRotationGroup" 
        android:pivotX="300.0" 
        android:pivotY="300.0" 
        android:rotation="0">
        <path
            android:name="myName" 
            android:fillColor="#000000" 
            android:pathData="M300,70 l 0,-70 70,70 0,0 -70,70z"/>
    </group>
</vector>
```

My AnimatedVectorDrawable:

```
<animated-vector 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
   android:drawable="@drawable/my_vector_drawable" >
     <target
         android:name="myRotationGroup" 
         android:animation="@animator/my_rotation" />
 </animated-vector>
```

And my ObjectAnimator:

```
<objectAnimator
     android:duration="500" 
     android:propertyName="rotation" 
     android:valueFrom="0" 
     android:valueTo="360" />
```

However, as you can see above, the final degree of rotation is set in the ObjectAnimator resource, as 360° for instance.

For my animation, how can I **change programmatically this final value**? The rotation degree need to be computed with some other data, so I don't know the target value before the animation starts.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: How do you made this work?

Answer (score 1):

*I think the solution is to create an object of ObjectAnimator in the class like this*

```
ObjectAnimator myRotation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(target,"rotation",360f);
myRotation.setDuration(500);
myRotation.start();    // this will start the animation

// here target is the object of the view on which you want to apply this animation 
// and you can change this 360f to any number at which degree you want to rotate
```

[for more information check this out](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation)